# Classifying files in a directory by file extension

Tags: python, python-2.x

I have the following code:

```
resolved = []
rejected = []
for file in files_within("./_input/"):
    file = File(file)
    if file.extension.lower() == "gdb":
        resolved.append(file)
    else:
        rejected.append(file)
MAP["resolved"] = resolved
MAP["rejected"] = rejected
```

And i would like to improve it to avoid this part:

```
MAP["resolved"] = resolved
MAP["rejected"] = rejected
```

But without affecting the performance.

I was thinking about that:

```
MAP["resolved"] = []
MAP["rejected"] = []
for file in files_within("./_input/"):
    file = File(file)
    if file.extension.lower() == "gdb":
        MAP["resolved"].append(file)
    else:
        MAP["rejected"].append(file)
```

But i don't know if is a good practice.

Python version 2.6.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each `MAP["resolved"]` has to perform a `hash` on `"resolved"`, and then check up the value in the dictionary's internal structure.
This is more costly then looking up a single variable.

Just like in the first, you can assign a local variable, `resolved`, but you can assign to the dictionary at the same time:

```
resolved = MAP["resolved"] = []
```

If you only mutate `resolved`, then you mutate `MAP["resolved"]` too. So you can't overwrite `resolved` with `resolved = ['new list']`, for example.
Which can get you:

```
MAP["resolved"] = resolved = []
MAP["rejected"] = rejected = []
for file in files_within("./_input/"):
    file = File(file)
    if file.extension.lower() == "gdb":
        resolved.append(file)
    else:
        rejected.append(file)
```

I am also unsure on what your functions are, I don't remember them being in the standard library, and so I won't suggest any changes to them.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that:

- you only have two possible results
- you can't have two files with the same name

Then you only need to iterate once and then make the set difference between the results.
Something like:

```
all_files = set([File(file) for file in files_within("./_input/")])
MAP["resolved"] = [file for file in all_files if file.extension.lower() == "gdb"]
MAP["rejected"] = list(all_files - set(MAP["resolved"]))
```

Note: I didn't test this, it's just the general idea.

EDIT: As pointed out, the original code stores `File` objects, not file paths.

Comment: The original code stores `File` objects; your solution stores the paths.

Comment: Ops, you're right, I missed that the `file` variable was the same one being re-assigned. I'll edit it to see if I can fix it.